# Using MAX() in mySQL query is giving problematic results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make multiple queries in order to find the most recent entry in a database by username.
Here's my code:

```
<?php  
    require_once("../includes/db_connection.php");  

    $userID = $_POST["userID"];
    $returnString = array();

    // Query the max id value of a given key_id (find the most recent upload)
    $query = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM photos WHERE key_id = {$userID}";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    //additional while loop could go here

    //now get the url where from the max id value that we just queried
    $query = "SELECT url FROM photos WHERE id = {$urlID}";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $returnString['url'] = $urlID;

    mysqli_free_result($result);        
    echo json_encode($returnString);


?>
```

I think the problem lies in the first query. When I return the result from that, I get:

`{"maxID": "current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}`

When I create a while loop to capture the array (why I need to do this is beyond me because it will only ever return 1 value):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {$returnString[] = $row;}
```

Then I get this funky result:

```
[{"MAX(id)":"30"}]
```

30 is the correct value, but then I don't know how to use that result in my next mySQL query.

***************UPDATE****************************

The query :

```
SELECT url FROM photos WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM photos WHERE key_id = {$userID});
```

Works perfectly when making the query from within mySQL, but doesn't work from my php script. It returns this weird string:

```
{"url":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}}
```

Here's the updated script:

```
require_once("../includes/db_connection.php");  

$userID = $_POST["userID"];
$returnString = array();

$query = "SELECT url FROM photos WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM photos WHERE key_id = {$userID})";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

mysqli_free_result($result);    

$returnString['url'] = $result; 
echo json_encode($returnString);
```

Comment: You're freeing your results before fetching the records. Add `$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);` before freeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer:

```
$query = "SELECT url FROM photos WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM photos WHERE key_id = {$userID})";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result):
$url = $row['url'];
echo json_encode($url);
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Comment: That seems to be throwing a server error.  I think the problem is that the result isn't 'id', but 'MAX(id)'.  $id = {$row['MAX(id)']};  doesn't work either. @NickC217

Comment: try {@row['id']} instead

Comment: Is that with or without the while loop?

Comment: That is for the $id = {$row['id']};  What is the column name is the first query?

Comment: "id".  The weird part is that if I use this query (from @Ken 's post above): $query = "SELECT url FROM photos WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM photos WHERE key_id = {$userID})";  I get the exact result I want when I'm making the query from mySQL, but from my php script I get this:
{"url":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}}

Comment: @ken query is the way to go.  But I guess my next question is what is the expected result you are trying to echo out with the PHP code.

Comment: it pulls the url of a photo. i.e.  myphoto.png   I updated my post.

Comment: That still throws a server error (500). I don't understand why. I even tried hardcoding the $userID value.  I think we're getting close.

Comment: Not sure why you get a server 500 error, but try changing the mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) to mysqli_fetch_array($result)

Comment: Tried them _assoc and _array and the error persists. The error is being thrown because of one (or both) of these two lines: 

`$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$url = {$row['url']};`

Comment: Update my answer again. changed fetch_array to fetch_row and moved up the echo.  Does that still give you same errors?

Comment: That totally worked!! I took the curly brackets off and voila!  Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Ok awesome, I actually went to some code I had and it worked with mysqli_fetch_array($result) and taking {} off the $row['url'].  Glad we were able to work it out.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something in the schema that's not apparent from code and comments, you can save yourself a roundtrip by combining your SQL commands.

```
$query = "SELECT id AS urlID, url FROM photos WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM photos WHERE key_id = {$userID})";
```

Then interface with your results like you normally would.

Comment: That looks like a much more efficient way of doing it. Let me try that! Thanks!

Comment: What does "SELECT id AS urlID, url" mean exactly?

Comment: `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: @Ken - Did you mean this instead:
$query = "SELECT url FROM photos WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM photos WHERE key_id = {$userID})";

Comment: @user2755541 the `SELECT field AS alias` syntax lets you reference the `id` field using `urlID` as an alias if you are using an associative array.

Comment: I included both the urlID and url in the results in case your code needs both. If you only need the URL, then your updated code should work just fine.

Comment: This is more efficient than the orig solution, indeed, but still not optimal;subselects aren't a good idea, generally, unless it's unavoidable.

Edit: something like select... from photos where key_id=... order by id desc limit 1 would probably perform better

Comment: @SteveHorvath great point. I didn't even notice both queries were against the same base table until your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real problem is in the loop and use of an array for the results.

You should change to a single query like:

```
SELECT url, MAX(id) as id FROM photos WHERE key_id = {$userID}
```

`MAX(id) as id` returns the aggregate column name as id

You don't need to loop with a `while` if you are only expecting one row. Just change the `while` to `if` to test if any row is returned, and assign the values to single variables:

```
$id = {$row['id']};
$url = {$row['url']};
```

The "funky" result is from trying to print the array which is not needed and has stored the column name and value.

Comment: I'm trying this but it's throwing an internal server error 500.